# using @react-oauth/google, the google login popup does not show any content

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to implement google login using the @react-oauth/google package in my application. what happens is that the button shows and when i click on the button, the google popup shows but it is blank. no content at all. please what could be the reason? and how do i fix it?

app.jsx

```
return (
    <>
      <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={ import.meta.env.VITE_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID }>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/">
              <Route path="" element={<Home />}/>
              <Route path="/createclub" element={<CreateClub />}/>
              <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />}/>
              <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}/>
              <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />}/>
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </GoogleOAuthProvider>
    </>
  )
```

and in my `login.js`

```
<GoogleLogin
    onSuccess={credentialResponse => {
    console.log(credentialResponse);
    }}
    onError={() => {
        console.log('Login Failed');
    }}
    />
```

in the console i get

```
client:180 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.
```

Please, why is the popup by the google login empty?